# Как сделать так, чтобы нельзя было писать слова?

Tags: python, типы-данных

Как сделать так, чтобы в переменную нельзя было писать ничего, кроме чисел? Желательно решение через типы данных или условия (я должен понять код, но я мало знаю о python).

Comment: Используйте язык со статической типизацией.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Числа бывают разных типов, не только натуральные, поэтому можно сделать каскадную проверку путем обработки ошибок при преобразовании. Комментарии в коде.

```
while True:
    number = input('Введите число: ')
    try:
        number = int(number)  # попытка преобразовать введенную строку в целое число
        break  # если попытка удачная, выходим из бесконечного цикла
    except ValueError:
        try:
            number = float(number)  # попытка преобразовать введенную строку в вещественное число (с плавающей запятой)
            break
        except ValueError:
            try:
                number = complex(number)  # попытка преобразовать введенную строку в комплексное число
                break
            except ValueError:
                print(f'{number} - не число!')  # когда ни одно из преобразований не удалось

# анализируем тип введенного числа
d = {int: 'целое', float: 'вещественное', complex: 'комплексное'}
print(f"Введено число {number} : {''.join([v for k, v in d.items() if isinstance(number, k)])}")
```

Примеры результатов:

```
Введите число: 100пятьсот
100пятьсот - не число!
Введите число: 100500
Введено число 100500 : целое

Введите число: inf
Введено число inf : вещественное

Введите число: 5-1200j
Введено число (5-1200j) : комплексное

Введите число: 123.458e50
Введено число 1.23458e+52 : вещественное
```

Answer (score 4):

"Писать" - через `input()`?
Тогда вот решение:

```
a=input('Введите число ')
while not a.isdigit():
   a=input('Введите ЧИСЛО ')
```

**P.S.** Как сказал @АлексейР, это работает только для целых положительных чисел :)

Comment: -1 число? а 1.2 число? а 1e10?